# Is it possible to rename and change the data type of a property in a Realm migration

Tags: ios, swift, migration, realm

I currently have an object with a property of `Double` and I would like to change it a `List` of `doubles`.

What would be the best way to change `price:Double` to `prices = List<Double>()` based on the following code?

Is it even possible to rename and change the data type of property in Realm migration? If not, what is typically done in this case, do I need to treat `prices` as a new property and remove the property `price` and then manually iterate through all of the items in Realm to make the change?

#### Before migration - what I currently have

```
class Item:Object{
    @objc dynamic var itemName:String = "General"
    @objc dynamic var price:Double = 0
}
```

#### After migration - What I want after migration

```
class Item:Object{
    @objc dynamic var itemName:String = "General"
    let prices = List<Double>()
}
```

#### Migration

The following migration doesn't work. How can I modify it to make it work?

```
/// Schema 1:
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            migration.renameProperty(onType: Item.className(), from: "price", to: "prices")
        }
})
```

Comment: You are not renaming a property here, you are creating an entirely different property type. I would suggest adding a new List property and taking the existing double value and appending it to the new List. You can use the Realm Guide [Updating Values](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-values) as a bit of a template for the process - that example is creating an entirely new property, fullName from existing ones, firstName and lastName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Person.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                 // Append price value to new prices list
                 let price = oldObject!["price"] as! Double
                 newObject!["prices"] = [price]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: @ rs7 - I tried it but I'm getting the following error: `Could not cast value of type 'RealmSwift.List<RealmSwift.DynamicObject>' (0x107923c48) to 'RealmSwift.List<Swift.Double>' (0x1079232f8).`

Comment: I changed my code - how about now? I would try `let prices = newObject.dynamicList("prices")` with the cast and if it fails, without.

Comment: @ rs7 - Thank you for your suggestions. Using `let prices = newObject!.dynamicList("prices") as! List<Double>` I get warning **Cast from 'List<DynamicObject>' to unrelated type 'List<Double>' always fails** and crashes when compiled. If I remove the casting and `let prices = newObject!.dynamicList("prices")` I get an error on `price` in the appending line `prices.append(price)` that says **Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'DynamicObject'**

Comment: @ rs7 - It worked, thanks a lot. The only thing I had to do was unwrap newObject, `newObject!["prices"] = [price]`. Is there any documentation you read that led you to the right answer?

Comment: Does that code actually work? I can't seem to implement it. This `newObject["prices"] = [price]` is throwing an error as [price] is undefined. What's that expected to be? [Double] isn't really valid - perhaps my model is different.

Comment: The Realm documentation is out of date and very incomplete in general. So your best bet if you can't find what you are looking for in the official documentation, is to look for it on the Realm forum or on Stack Overflow. I had to look at multiple questions in order to come up with the right answer.